# Core Data: restore from backup on different device

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, backup

Data saved with Core Data is part of the iTunes backup, so if you 'backup and restore' on your phone all your application data should be back.

I have been getting user reports that when migrating to a different device like a new phone, a 'restore from backup' on the new phone does not restore the application data. Are there any further means necessary to fix this? Unfortunately I don't have a second device at hand for verification. Thank you